# Spring loaded folder settings missing in Yosemite

Tags: macos, finder

My spring loaded folder settings are missing from the Finder prefs in Yosemite.

[image: Finder > Preferences > General]

What might be the cause of this and how do I get all my options back?

FYI, I do have XtraFinder 0.25.4 installed but the option didn't move to the prefs there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that these settings have been removed from the Finder preferences window.

- The slider is now located in System Preferences → Accessibility → Mouse & Trackpad

  [image]
- You can change the spring-loaded delay by writing the setting manually:

  ```
  defaults write -g com.apple.springing.delay -float 1.0 && killall -HUP Finder
  ```

  Replace `1.0` with the delay in seconds before springing.

Comment: Any idea how to get them to show up again? The spring loading speed is causing problems.

Comment: @eComEvo I've found where the preference has been moved to.