# El Capitan issue: Drag-and-Drop to open an image with the Preview.app in the Finder Toolbar not working

Tags: finder, preview, macos

El Capitan issue: Drag-and-Drop to open an image with the Preview.app in the Finder Toolbar is not working ... dragging an image over the preview.app icon in my finder windows toolbar it results in an forbiden icon an nothing happens ...

[image]

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Did this work in Yosemite?

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable the option with a somewhat misleading name "spring-loading delay". It is now a component of System Preferences → Accessibility → Mouse & Trackpad, see answer at [Spring loaded folder settings missing in Yosemite](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/189525/spring-loaded-folder-settings-missing-in-yosemite)

Answer (score 0):

Curiously, many applications, no matter the location of the icon you drag to, will now (El Capitan) refuse to open the dragged file. Apparently these apps are controlled by custom permissions. I have always had TextEdit in my Finder window toolbar for the convenience of drag and open. On a hunch I duplicated TextEdit.app and renamed the duplicate to TextEditor.app (cleaner appearance without the -copy there). I found that the duplicate does open dragged files. I added TextEditor.app to my Finder toolbar and it works as desired there too. I hope this helps.