# Is there a way to increase the speed of the "hover open folder" thing when drag and dropping?

Tags: mac, finder, macos, mouse

So when you drag and drop a file, while you are still holding it, you can move the file to say on a folder and hover there for like 2 seconds and that will open up the folder for you and you can continue to navigate using the same method until you are where you want to be and release your mouse to finally drop the file there. Now the hover takes like 2 seconds, that is way to long. Is there a way to decrease this time and make this procedure faster?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not strictly a duplicate of [Spring loaded folder settings missing in Yosemite](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/189525/spring-loaded-folder-settings-missing-in-yosemite) however the answer is the same, so I'll save future Googlers some effort by copying it, with slight modification, to here.

> **Spring-Loaded Folders**
>
> - The slider is located in System Preferences → Accessibility → Mouse & Trackpad
>
>   [image]
> - You can change the spring-loaded delay by writing the setting manually:
>
>   ```
>   defaults write -g com.apple.springing.delay -float 1.0 && killall -HUP Finder
>   ```
>
>   Replace `1.0` with the delay in seconds before springing.

Credit to [grgarside](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/37797/grgarside)

Comment: @grgarside - most welcome indeed, credit where credit is due :)